# Implementing specific count query in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
class memberclass {
   function Available()
   {
      if(!$this->DBLogin()) {
          $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
          return false;
      }

      $ux = $_SESSION['username_of_user'];

      $qry = "Select (one='Not done') + (two='Not done') + (three='Not done') + (four='Not done') + (five='Note done') As num_not_done From $this->tablename Where  username='$ux'";
      $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $qry);
      $result_length = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      echo "$result_length";
   }
}
```

I'm trying to show the amount of available items. So for every column where the value is "Not done" for a user it should sum it up in the query to form the total amount of "Not done" items. However when I try to show this number with the following code, I get the value "1" for each user for some reason:

```
<?= $memberclass->Available(); ?>
```

Comment: have you heared about SUM() and GROUP BY?

Comment: @jakubwrona I have tried `"Select SUM((one='Not done') + (two='Not done') + (three='Not done') + (four='Not done') + (five='Note done')) As num_not_done From $this->tablename Where  username='$ux'";`
   ` But it still gives the same result

Comment: I didn't mean this... could you provide an example of data from the table you are querying?

Comment: @jakubwrona [link](http://prntscr.com/cundm2)  So what I want the code to do is count the amount of times it says "Not done" for a user (so that row). So then I can implement it in HTML as a statistic. Tasks not completed: `<? php code here ?>` For the row in the link I sent you it would say: Tasks not completed: 5.

Comment: Why do you store strings instead of 1 or 0 for DONE or NOT DONE ? This problem is about how you store the data, not about query complexity.

Comment: @Heroselohim because I wanted to display the results directly from the database so users can see "Not done"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need cast the expressions to INT and then sum them. For MySQL database your query could look like this:

```
SELECT (CAST(one='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + 
           CAST(two='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + 
           CAST(three='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + 
           CAST(four='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) +
           CAST(five='Not done' AS UNSIGNED)) as num_not_done 
FROM  tableName WHERE username = 'something'
```

Comment: `$ux = $_SESSION['username_of_user']; 
 $qry = "SELECT (CAST(one='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(two='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(three='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(four='Not done' AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(five='Not done' AS UNSIGNED)) as num_not_done FROM  $this->tablename WHERE username = '$ux'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $qry);
        $result_length = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  
 echo "$result_length";`   I still get the result "1" for each user, your code sounds logical but it just doesn't seem to work. All I know is that the answer lies in the query.

Comment: the number of rows will be one, but the only row will contain an index called "num_not_done" which will contain the right number. So do a fetch_array and then display the $fetched[0]['num_dot_done']